# Overwriting an object

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have a situation where I get a reference to an object that I would like to "overwrite" with another object of the same type. I know by design that the objects are of the same type. I do not have access to the parent object in this function.

The dataobject is defines as like:

```
    Class DataObject
    {
         public List<int> Stuff = new List<int>();
    }
```

Then there is a method

```
    void DoStuff(object obj)
    {
         // At this point I know that obj is List<int>
         // Create new object from some source
         var newList = new List<int>();

         // Here I would like to make the passed object the new object
         (the pointer of obj) = (the pointer of newlist)
    }
```

I don't know if this is possible. It's just something I've been banging my head against for a couple of hours now and my brain seems to have stopped working.

Thanks in advance

Johan

Comment: You are not acttly just trying to replace the contents of Stuff are you? eg `void DoStuff() { this.Stuff = new List<int>; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass object [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

```
void DoStuff(ref DataObject dataObject)
{
    dataObject = ...;
}
```

`ref object` won't be allowed here, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Clone function but take a look at the following [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c) link that has a nice method for cloning objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible with your current code - the reference is passed by value, and is thus entirely independent of how you originally accessed it. Even if you changed `obj` to be a `ref` parameter, you wouldn't be able to call the method with `ref Stuff` because the types would be incorrect. You could *potentially* do it with a generic parameter:

```
void DoStuff<T>(ref T obj)
{
    object newList = new List<int>();
    obj = (T) newList;
}
```

That's pretty horrible though.

It's normally a design smell to *want* to do this - if you can explain more about the bigger picture, we may be able to help more.

Comment: I have a Command object model that allows for piping commands together. A command is of type CommandBase<Tin, Tout> where the T:s are the model. I use delegates to pipe commands to different parts of the model if the signatures of the commands doesn't match. That is if A -> B with data A.Outdata.List -> B.Indata I map them using CommandA.PipeResultTo<CommandB>().MapInput(e=>e.Outdata.List). At the point of writing that statement, e.Outdata is null since the previous command hasn't been executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

`obj = newList` what difference it will make if pointer of obj is changed to newList or pointer of newList will be changed to obj?

Comment: Because obj is a member of the main DTO. If you do the above the main object will still reference to old one and obj will just be a reference to the new one.